# Returning The Wrong Size Class

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, retina-display, size-classes

The iPad Retina simulator returns false when asking for:

```
traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass == .regular
```

Call in viewWillAppear:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    updateForRegularWidth()
}

func updateForRegularWidth() {
    print(traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass == .regular)//prints false
    if traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass == .regular {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Anyone has an idea why? It's pretty clear from the documentation that it shouldn't.

Comment: Instead of checking for true of false, can you just check what size class it actually returns?

Comment: no idea why I didn't do that. It returns horiz: UIUserInterfaceSizeClass |Raw: 1 --- vert: UIUserInterfaceSizeClass |Raw: 2 ||| No idea why it returns 1 for horizontal on an iPad (the app is full screen by the way).

Comment: traitCollection also returns a userInterfaceIdiom value. It checks for iPad in that case.

Comment: yeah, but for splitView and slideOver i need to know the right horizontal side class though.